# 3D model in GLB not positioned correctly with model-viewer

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, maya, model-viewer

We are trying to load a GLB model (AR compatible) into a web application using [model-viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) library. But, the model is placed **too** close to the camera and it's not rendered correctly with different `camera-orbit` and `camera-target` values. We start to think that something has gone wrong while the animation developer exported the model into GLB file. Any inputs/ answers that can help us to move towards the right direction is appreciated.

Below is the screenshot from https://spase.io/playground for reference.

[image: GLB position wrong]

Comment: Looks as though the model is defined as y-up, but your viewer is rendering with z-up? Prior to exporting you can always create a new parent transform for the entire model, scale down by some value (e.g. 0.01), and rotate around the X axis by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the .glb file also has a camera attached with the model. Try to check the 3D model, if there is a camera, delete it and reupload to see if that helps.